# Format PHP Results

Tags: php, html, sql

I am looking to take the contents of a single row in SQL along with the headers and format them like so:

```
Name: lastname, firstname
address: 123 pine st
zip: 12345
```

Instead of them being pulled and displayed in PHP in a table like format.

Comment: How far along are you in the process? What have you tried?

Comment: Your question is missing a question-mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Give this a go:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    printf('Name: %s, %s<br/>', $row['fist_name'], $row['last_name']);
    printf('address: %s<br/>', $row['address']);
    printf('zip: %s', $row['zip']);
}
```

Since you didn't list your SQL schema I can't define some of the printf parameters more accurately. So take a look at the printf method in the PHP manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Comment: Works but the function is wrong =(

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() ------ I am useing MSSQL and changing out mysql for MSSQL does not work

Comment: Hmmm. Take a look at this: [MSSQL FETCH ARRAY](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php) . Let me know if that doesn't work. Sorry for the MySQL assumption.